# exponential function's limit

Tags: limits, functions, exponential-function

I have been over this problem for a long time now and I just can't figure the way out.

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} ((1.5^x + ([(1+ 0.0001)^{10000}])^x)^{1/x}$$ where  [.] represents greatest integer function

From Binomial theorem, it is evident to me that I can write the sequence as $$
\lim_{x\to \infty} ((1.5^x + (2)^x)^{1/x}$$

I am completely stuck over this step and don't know how to move ahead.

P.S. Wolfram shows that the answer is $2$ but I  just don't know how to calculate it.

Comment: Did you mean $[(1+ 0.0001)^{10000}]$ because $[1+ 0.0001]^{10000}=1^{10000}$

Comment: Ya, just give me a second to edit it.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to \infty} ((1.5^x + (2)^x)^{1/x}=2\lim_{x\to \infty} (((\frac{3}{4})^x +1)^{1/x}$